# how to convert from array of object to array of values? 5

Tags: laravel-5

I write this code:

```
$menu_cat= DB::table('menu') ->get();
$cat_ids = DB::table('category')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('parent',0 )
        ->whereNotIn('id',$menu_cat )
        ->get();
```

but I get error 
Object of class stdClas  could not be converted to string
$menu_cat is array of object how to convert $menu_cat to array of integer???

Comment: You need to pluck one column from menu table